Cloudwatch Insight Query -Parse to Extract Values
I wish to extract two fields from my cloudwatch logs and combine them to display, potentially use them to de-dupe later on.  My log is json-based.
My log looks like the follow

@message: "{ "timestamp": "2024-10-21T04:06:01,772", "logger":
"com.nsc.Gairobea.GetActivity", "level": "ERROR", "exception":
"java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException\n....", ...}

Questions:

How do I extract "Gairobea" as a new field "domain"? like the first capitalized the word in logger use the parse command?
How do I get the string "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException" using the parse command.  The new field will be "cause".
Can I combine "domain" and "cause" into a new string and display it?

